# vue 3 and .NET Core 3.1 hot module reload issues

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core-3.1, vuejs3

I created a web app with netcore3.1 and vue3 (with 'vue create myapp')

I get errors in console

> GET https://192.168.12.111:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1612001548818
> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR sockjs.js?9be2:1609
> [WDS] Disconnected!

I run .NET Core on default "applicationUrl":

```
https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000
```

I did not added webpack in my client app (not yet) but I receive the WDS disconnected

Seems webpack is already included in 'vue create' builtin template

I want my client and backend run in same domain: I not want enable CORS.

So I edited my vue.config.js in this way

```
 devServer: {
    proxy: 'https://localhost:5001/',
 },
```

My startup class of .NET Core:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options => options.RootPath = "ClientApp");  

        services
        .AddMyDatabaseContext(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetValue<string>("Default"))
        .AddRepositories()
        .AddMappers()
        .AddServices()
        .AddControllers()
        .AddValidation()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(...)
        .AddJsonOptions(...);

        services.AddIdentity...AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(...).AddJwtBearer(...);

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles(); 
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve");
            }
            else
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "dist";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With that setup can I work well with backend but can't have hot reload.

Could someone help me to understand what I should do to remove that error?
Do I have to install webpack? Do I need to change above setup?